# Old house, want to update thermostat

Tags: electrical, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, boiler, radiator

I bought an older house (1897!) and am slowly but surely going around and repairing things and updating them. I want to update my thermostat to an ecobee one. We only have radiators and no AC, but that thermostat will unlock automation in the winter and allow us to hook up a few security sensors.

Attached is a picture of what I have now. What should I do? I dont see any colors on them, and there are only two, so I'm wondering if it's really old. My boiler is only about 10 years old and is a Burnham. Should I run a whole new set of wires so I have more connections?

Thank you!

[image: My current wall]

Comment: Looks like you have a white and a red. If you take the base plate off the wall there might be some more wires that aren't in use and tucked back in where the wires come out or wrapped around a cable. Those wires look pretty old, so I wouldn't be surprised if this turned out to be not the case, but it's well worth a small bit of effort to check.

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your boiler please?

Answer (score 2):

Your existing thermostat is simply an on/off control.  Two wire thermostats are still available and will work. I will take a SWAG and highly recommend replacing the wire with the new thermostat. I expect the new thermostat will need more then two wires. This becomes more important as you go to a "smart" thermostat and update your HVAC system. I would recommend getting at least 7 conductor cable, extras can be left unconnected. For a better answer we will need to know what thermostat and heating plant you have.